# Resizing old post thumbnail images

Tags: post-thumbnails

In my `functions.php` I have defined the following:

```
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
set_post_thumbnail_size( 475, 475, true );
```

I have used the **Regenerate Thumbnails** plugin to regenerate the thumbnails.

When calling `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`, the images do not look cropped. When checking my uploads folder I do not see any thumbnails set for 475x475.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've figured this out. Appears as though I really wanted `add_image_size('post', 475, 475, true);` and then reran the **Regenerate Thumbnails** plugin. After sorting out a permissions error on `/wp-content/uploads`, this worked great.

Then in my theme, I just displayed this image size for the post thumbnail. `the_post_thumbnail('post');`

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you'd like to use `<?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>`, but i'd use timthumb:

1. install http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/katalyst-timthumb/
2. instead of `the_post_thumbnail()` try `<?php the_post_thumbnail( array(475,475) ); ?>`

hope it works ;)

Comment: Thanks for this. While this is an easy fix, I'd prefer something built in.

Comment: ok so try this with the same code and plugin you used before : 1) set media size in config -> media -> 475x475 2) regenerate thumbnails 3) check if it worked

Comment: If I change my medium thumbnail, that won't affect post-thumbnail will it? Just attachment thumbnail is my understanding.

Comment: well, i'm not sure what you're up too, i'd change the default size